# sea battle game / prevent typing the same thing twice

Tags: javascript

such a problem is that if I enter the same number 3 times and it counts for me as a win, but I need to prohibit it so that I cannot enter the same number a second time, can you tell me how to do this?

```js
let randomLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)
let location1 = randomLocation
let location2 = location1 + 1
let location3 = location2 + 1
let guess
let hits = 0
let guesses = 0
let isSunk = false

while (isSunk == false) {
  guess = prompt('Enter the coordonation: ')
  let secondTime = guess
  if (guess < 0 || guess > 6) {
    alert('Your number is incorrect')
  } else {
    guesses++
    if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
      alert('SHOT')
      hits++


      if (hits == 3) {
        isSunk = true
        alert('The ship was wrecked')
      }
    } else {
      alert('you missed')
    }
  }
}
let stats = 'You wrecked from ' + guesses + ' attempts ' + ' which means you have statistics ' + (3 / guesses)
console.log(stats)
```

Comment: Have you thought about storing the numbers of shots in a table and adding a condition to check whether the number is already in the collection, then prompt user for input again?

Comment: You have to keep track of which location(s) have already been "shot". You could just set the location to `-1` when hit. That might already magically work. How can a user successfully sink a ship if Math.random() chooses `5` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to check to see if the user has entered the same thing before.  Use a `Set`.

```js
let answers = new Set();
while(true) {
  let input = prompt('Enter something')
  if (input == null) break;
  if (answers.has(input)) {
    alert('You already entered that.');
  } else {
    alert('That is new!')
    answers.add(input);  // Remember this input for later.
  }
}
```